# Is there a way to pass locator "by" as a string on protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm trying to avoid using a switch-case to verify the locator and then creating an element.

This is how my code looks like:

```
    switch (name.by) {
        case "class":
            return element(by.className(name.value));
        case "cssselector":
            return element(by.cssSelector(name.value));
        case "id":
            return element(by.id(name.value));
        case "linktext":
            return element(by.linkText(name.value));
        case "name":
            return element(by.name(name.value));
        case "partiallinktext":
            return element(by.partialLinkText(name.value));
        case "tagname":
            return element(by.tagName(name.value));;
        case "xpath":
            return element(by.xpath(name.value));;
        default:
            throw new Error ('Invalid option.');
    }
```

It receives as a param a json structure like this:

```
"rangeFrom": {
   "by": "id",
   "value": "txtRentFrom"
},
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
element(by[name.by](name.value));
```

Does anyone know if there's a way to avoid using switch-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const dict = {
"class": by.classname,
"cssselector": by.cssSelector
...
}

return element(dict[name.by](name.value));
```